# Why does normal force decrease if a body rotates on and around another smooth body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

We've an system of a sphere (Radius $R$) and a point particle of mass $m$.

This particle is at rest on a smooth sphere, we've then $N=mg$

Now I poke it and it begins to revolve **on** and around it due to its gravitational pull.

We've then $\frac{m v^{2}}{R}=m g-N$

In the second case clearly the normal reaction is lesser than the stationary case.

But how does one intuitively explain this?
Why does the particle press down on the sphere more when at rest than when in motion?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The particle in motion is accelerating toward the center of the sphere, while the particle at rest is not.  It's ultimately the same reason that you feel lighter in an elevator which is accelerating downward.

Comment: Thank you dear J. Murray. I can feel that if the floor slips away I'll feel less normal reaction, and it's because I'm not pressing down on the floor as I was before. But due to my weak imagination I can't feel that it'll be the same for a rotating body.

Comment: @YasirSadiq Have you ever ridden a skateboard or a bicycle down a hill? As long as you're accelerating downward, you feel slightly lighter than you do while riding on flat ground.  The surface of the sphere in question is just like a very gently sloping hill.